# madSHI MadExcept equivalent for .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, delphi

I am a C# newbie having spent a lot of time with Delphi I am switching to .NET. A great package used for exception stack reporting etc. was madExcept from http://madshi.net/madExceptScreenShots.htm.

Is there something equivalent for .NET (C#). What I am after is something that will provide me with a stack trace when an exception occurs. If so, I am assuming I would have to deploy the debug versions of assemblies as that would have the necessary symbol information? Or could I provide a separate debug MAP file instead?

All pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: "All pointers greatly appreciated?"  Sorry, can't help you. C# doesn't use pointers. ;)

Comment: @mason C# does indeed have pointers

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yup, it has pointers, but you need to wrap them in unsafe code blocks if you want to use them.

Comment: @Runner You can do it that way, or you can pin and use `AddrOfPinnedObject` and avoid unsafe blocks.

Comment: Way to seriously miss the point...   Commentators! GET BACK ON TRACK! :)

Comment: @Mason: Nice pun. Others (especially Arafangion): Get a sense of humor - Mason clearly added a **;)** to indicate it was a joke.

Comment: @KenWhite: I see that I forgot to wink. ;)

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close for a duplicate because the other question has nothing to do with Delphi, and this question is asking explicitly for something which works just like MadExcept, but for C# instead. Although the accepted answer in the other question may suit the needs of this question, and is a valuable link to refer to in an answer, the other question doesn't explicitly mention anything about MadExcept for Delphi at all. However, I am neutral because this is a subjective question and I'm shocked that it's getting upvotes based on the FAQ.

Comment: I'm sure there are some far differences between exception handlers for Delphi and C#, based on the existence of garbage collectors.

Comment: Multiple duplicates. Here's another duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333953/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-exception-printstacktrace

Comment: http://exceptionreporter.codeplex.com/ : Almost exactly like MadExcept

Comment: @JerryDodge: Actually the difference has nothing to do with Garbage Collection, I think the main difference is that it is documented in C#, but Delphi didn't standardise it (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Delphi, C# exceptions will give you the stack trace if they are available through the [`Exception.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) property.

If you want alternatives for other aspects of MadExcept (of which there are a fair few), you should ask them explicitly.